# data json не распознает как массив

Tags: jquery, массивы, json

```
success:function (data) {
               console.log(data);
```

дает 
["name","price"] нормально

```
console.log(data[0]);
```

ничего не дает

Comment: строка потому что у вас на входе, а не массив

Comment: как поменять на массив?

Answer (score 0):

Наверное. единственный случай почему такое может происходить, заключается в том, что data - это не объект/массив, а обычная строка. Видимо сервер не выставляет заголовки `content-type` в `applcation/json`, а jquery не догадывается о типе данных (на основании этих заголовков и происходит преобразование). Так что, либо делайте принудительно

```
success: function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data); 
    console.log(data[0]);
}
```

либо используйте `$.getJSON` вместо `$.get` или `$.ajax` с `type: "GET"`. Для POST-запросов, очевидно, только первый вариант, либо настроить заголовки сервера

зы: судя по вашему предыдущему вопросу, на стороне сервера следует сделать так

```
$data = array('name' => $name, 'price' => $price);
$data = json_encode($data);

header("Content-Type: application/json");
print ($data);
```

Comment: data = JSON.parse(data); дает ошибку. я добавил весь код аджакса, можете посмотреть

Comment: @DimaRashevskiy какую ошибку?

Comment: возможно пхп выводит еще что-то помимо "массива". попроубйте добавить `die()` после `print`

Comment: VM15774:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position  4

Comment: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: да, через alert выводит совсем другие значения, которых быть даже не должно